# How to extract file name as a string when iterating over files using `pathlib.Path().glob()`?

Tags: python, annotations, filenames, glob, pathlib

```py
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

Reports = Path('path/text').glob('*.txt')
for report in Reports:
    raw_text = open(report).read()
    TAB = pd.read_csv('path/tables/*.ann')
```

I'm using `pathlib.Path().glob()` to iterate over all `.txt` files under the **text** directory. For each `path/text/file_name.txt`, there is a corresponding `.ann` file `path/tables/file_name.ann` (same file name) under the **tables** directory, and I need the table to process the raw text accordingly. Is there a convenient way to open the corresponding `.ann` file?

Can I extract the path-to-file of each `.txt` file as a string `S`, and then

```py
S =                        # extract a path-to-file string from report
file = S.replace('text','tables').replace('txt','ann')
TAB = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Hopefully there would be a better approach.

Comment: You could do `file = report.parents[1].joinpath('tables').joinpath(report.name[:-3] + 'ann')`. But I think it would be better to set `path_tables = Path('path/tables')` before the loop and then use `file = path_tables.joinpath(report.name[:-3] + 'ann')`. (Just a thought.)

Comment: @Timus Thank you very much! Both work very well! You can make it an answer if you want, and then I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, that's very nice of you ... but I think it's okay this way.